# Why do I need to run Memgraph Platform in interactive mode?

Tags: memgraphdb

I tried to run Memgraph Platform using `docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform` and it works.

Then I tried `docker run -i -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform` and it also worked.

But if I run `docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform` I get the message that Memgraph lab is at port 3000 but I can't open it.

When I try to run different Docker image there is no need for `-i` and it all works, e.g. `docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph`

Comment: What is the actual error? Have you tried `-d`?

Comment: I can't connect to port 3000. With detached mode the situation is the same.

C:\Users\tasrh>docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                            PORTS                                                                    NAMES
7b3696327685   memgraph/memgraph-platform   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/bi…"   About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                                                                              exciting_swirles

Comment: Yes the image is exited but you can still access it's logs. Could you check them?